# Need to modify javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
0: {id: "GD721OGWRF", quantity: "1", Size: "Medium", Colour: "Red"}
```

And i need to modify it to have like that:

```
{id: "GD721OGWRF", quantity: "1", Size: "Medium", Colour: "Red"}
```

Comment: What's the question? What have you tried? See [ask].

Comment: You mean like `let modified = array[0];` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to unwrap the first value, you can destructure it fairly easy. Make sure the variable is a `let` or `var` and not a `const`.

```js
let data = [{ id: "GD721OGWRF", quantity: "1", Size: "Medium", Colour: "Red" }];

[data] = data; // Destructure the first item (unwrap the first result)

console.log(data); // Print the modified object.
```